# Javascript Form Validation - jsFiddle Error

Tags: javascript, html, validation

I am attempting to display a hidden error list onsubmit if any inputs are blank. I keep getting an error in jsFiddle stating "Shell form does not validate." I checked my syntax and it looks okay (I am new so, I may be missing something).

Any help is appreciated!

https://jsfiddle.net/2mpg7mbj/

HTML:

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="errors">
  <p>The following field(s) must be filled out:</p>
  <ul id="errorList">

  </ul>
</div>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="validateForm()">
  <label for="A">Name</label>
    <input id="A" name="A" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <label for="B">Age</label>
    <input id="B" name="B" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <label for="C">City</label>
    <input id="C" name="C" type="text">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#errors {
  display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function validateForm()
{

  var errorMsg = '';
  var errorDisplay = document.getElementByID('errors').style;
  var errorList = document.getElementByID('errorList');

    var name = document.getElementByID('A').value;
  var age = document.getElementByID('B').value;
  var city = document.getElementByID('C').value;

  if (name === '') {
    errorMsg += '<li>Name</li>';
  };

  if (age === '') {
    errorMsg += '<li>Age</li>';
  };

  if (city === '') {
    errorMsg += '<li>City</li>';
  };

    if (errorMsg.length != '') {
    errorList.innerHTML = errorMsg;
    errorDisplay.display = 'block';
    return false;
  };

return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your form to

```
<form method="POST" action='/endpoint'  onsubmit="validateForm(event)">
  <label for="A">Name</label>
  ...
```

and then in the script you need to change `document.getElementByID(...)` to `document.getElementById(...)` ("Id" instead of "ID") and preventDefault() on the event that is passed in to stop the default form submission process.

```
function validateForm(event) {
  ...
  if(errorMsg.length){
    ...
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/2mpg7mbj/2/

Comment: Thanks! This was chosen because not only did it do what I wanted, it also prevented the form from submitting.

Answer (score 1):

Some syntax issues:

Remove `;` after your all `if` blocks:

```
if (age === '') {

    errorMsg += '<li>Age</li>';
}
```

`errorMsg.length` returns a number, not string.

```
if (errorMsg.length !== 0) {

   errorList.innerHTML = errorMsg;
   errorDisplay.display = 'block';
   return false;
}
```

Change document.getElementBy**ID**() to `document.getElementById()`

[Demo with all fixed issues](https://jsfiddle.net/2mpg7mbj/11/)

Comment: Thanks! This accomplished my goal, except, it allowed the form to re-submit. Using the method that Steven noted below blocked the form submission.

Answer (score 0):

You have not added jquery in fiddle so have added basic jQuery. Hope I have done exactly as you want.

```js
function validateForm()
{
  var errorMsg = ''
  var errorDisplay = $("#errors");
  var errorList = $("#errorList"); 
  errorList.find("li").remove();
 var name = $("#A").val();
  var age = $("#B").val();
  var city = $("#C").val();
  if (!name) {
   errorMsg += '<li>Name</li>';
  }
  
  if (!age) {
   errorMsg += '<li>Age</li>';
  }
  
  if (!city) {
   errorMsg += '<li>City</li>';
  }

 if (errorMsg.length > 0) {
   errorList.append(errorMsg);
   errorDisplay.css("display","block");
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
   return true;
  }
}
```

```css
#errors {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="errors">
  <p>The following field(s) must be filled out:</p>
  <ul id="errorList">
    
  </ul>
</div>

<form method="POST" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
  <label for="A">Name</label>
    <input id="A" name="A" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <label for="B">Age</label>
    <input id="B" name="B" type="text">
  <br><br>
  <label for="C">City</label>
    <input id="C" name="C" type="text">
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```